# ivy - create local repository to pull multiple jar files from same location

Tags: ant, ivy

I have a local repository, in which i can put one jar and retrieve it using ivy. Now for svnant, I want to put 4 jar files in one folder and try to use ivy to retrieve it. my patten in org/module/version/module-version.jar. how do i perform this.

Answer (score 2):

In your **ivysettings.xml** file define a [filesystem](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/latest-milestone/resolver/filesystem.html) resolver with an artifact pattern matching the location of your 4 jars.

```
<ivysettings>
    <settings defaultResolver="local-repo"/>
    <resolvers>
        <filesystem name="local-repo">
             <ivy pattern="${ivy.settings.dir}/repo/[organisation]/[module]/[revision]/ivy.xml"/>
             <artifact pattern="${ivy.settings.dir}/repo/[organisation]/[module]/[revision]/[artifact]-[revision].[ext]"/>
        </filesystem>
    </resolvers>
</ivysettings>
```

Ivy will then be able to find your jars.

### Update

In order to group the 4 jars as one module save the following ivy.xml file and store it with the jars

```
<ivy-module version="2.0">
  <info organisation="myorg" module="svnant" revision="1.0"/>
  <publications>
    <artifact name="svnant"/>
    <artifact name="svnclientadapter"/>
    <artifact name="svnkit"/>
    <artifact name="svnjavahl"/>
  </publications>
</ivy-module>
```

**Note:** The revision number in the *ivy.xml* must match the revision number of the module

The dependency in the *ivy.xml* file is then

```
<dependency org="myorg" name="svnant" rev="1.0"/>
```

Comment: my jar files are svnant.jar, svnclientadapter.jar, svnkit.jar, svnjavahl.jar

what would my <dependency> look like

I am trying to avoid using 4 dependency entries

Comment: i'm looking around google for few hours and can't get the amazingly lightweight ivy to run.. weird files, settings, errors, files are not resolvable.. grrr.